# Webpack image bundling from a non-standard image reference

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, aurelia

I am using Webpack to bundle my Aurelia application. I wrote a custom attribute that provides a parallax effect on any element I apply it to. It works really well. I am not sure how to have Webpack detect the image references in my markup and bundle the referenced images.

```html
<div id="hero" scroll-parallax="image-extend: 50; image-file-height: 2688; image-file-width: 4000; image-source: ../media/hero.jpg; background-position: center top;">
```

The image gets inserted into the DOM during the Aurelia lifecycle as a child `<img>` element e.g., `createElement('img')`, and `img.src = this.imageSource`.

I explored using `html-loader.attrs` but from my initial tests it attempted to use the entire attribute value, not parse the attribute for an image value.

I have also tried to just use a `require` statement in my view model that uses the CustomAttribute and while the image did get added to the bundle, the real reference to the image in markup wasn't properly replaced like it would if it were a standard `<img src="">`.

I have also explored changing how the `src` gets set in the CustomAttribute to use `requires(this.imageSource)`. This causes Webpack to warn about a "critical dependency", (because of the theoretically dynamic nature of the dependency) and the image is not bundled.

I realize that I could configure the copy files plugin to copy the images I need but what I would like would be for a loader to detect the `image-source` above, bundle the image (via `url-loader` or `file-loader`) and replace the reference as if it was standard `src`. Is there a way to accomplish this with a combination of built in loaders or would one or more custom loaders be needed? Or should I explore including the image resource in a more Webpack "friendly" way?

Answer (score 0):

A few options, I'm sure there are more ways:

1. (difficulty: high) write your own webpack loader/extend html-loader plugin to parse it
2. (difficulty: easy) break out image-source to its own attribute, parse that attribute from your current attribute, then use `attr` option in html-loader so webpack will find/include it: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#advanced-options
3. (difficulty: easy) place images in a static file directory that is copied on build, the aurelia cli webpack scaffolded projects already does this so you could just include your images there.  I believe they are only copied once when starting `au run` so if you add new images you'll have to restart it.

Comment: Thanks. When I wrote the question I did something similar to three just to be unblocked. It's not ideal as it requires me to handle these images differently than all the other images in the app e.g., segregated into their own path or modify the Webpack copy plugin each time. I believe 2 would require me to rewrite the CustomAttribute as something else (since it would be two attributes).